# GTD in Gmail: a label with older starred emails first

Tags: date, gmail, reverse

I would like to have starred emails in reverse order (older emails first) but this is not possible in Gmail.So I was thinking to write an Apps Script.

The logic I tought is:

1. use GmailLabel to get all threads that have "starred" as label
2. cycle all messages to get the GmailMessage.getDate() and put them in an ordered array
3. add a new label "GTD-ToDo" to the messages... but I'm not sure if Gmail will show the messages in the label ordered "by date" or by "Last added to label"

Anyone has a different approach that could help me ?
Thank you

Comment: I did some coding to fetch all starred threads, reverse order and add a label to each thread adding labels to older threads first, but still the threads are shown as “recent first” based on date and not on the order I added the label to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I successfully changed the order of threads.

Just note:
=> addLabel() to a thread/message does **not** change the order of threads
=> createDraftReply() **does change the order* of threads

So if you want to change the order of threads with a label, the only tweak I found is to order IDs in an array and then cicle through the threads and call createDraftReply().
This will result in having threads in the order you want.
**Unfortunately**, you will also see a draft message at the end of each thread.

Any better ideas ?
Here is my code:

```
// Put starred threads into a label ordered "older first"
function ordinaGTD() {
  Logger.log("# Starred threads: " + GmailApp.getStarredThreads().length);
  var speciali= GmailApp.getStarredThreads(); // Get all starred threads
  var etichetta= GmailApp.createLabel("GTD"); // This label is the one I want messages ordered into
  
  // remove label to all current messages, just to clean things up
  var da_rimuovere=etichetta.getThreads(); 
  for(var k=0;k<da_rimuovere.length;k++) da_rimuovere[k].removeLabel(etichetta);

// Cicle through all starred and add IDs to an array using push()
var ordine=[];
for (var i=0; i < speciali.length; i++){
  // Prende la data del primo messaggio
  var quando = speciali[i].getLastMessageDate();
  // Crea un vettore "riga"
  // Mette la riga in tabella
  ordine.push(speciali[i].getId());
}

// Add a draft reply in each thread, the last reply is "more recent" so it will be shown first

// Crea un messaggio Draft per averli in ordine dal più recente
for(j=0;j<ordine.length;j++){
  Logger.log(ordine[j]);
  var t = GmailApp.getThreadById(ordine[j]);
  var messaggi=t.getMessages();
  Logger.log("Data primo MSG: "+messaggi[0].getDate().getTime());
  // In case there is already a draft, remove it
  var ultimo=messaggi[messaggi.length-1];
  if (ultimo.isDraft() && ultimo.getBody().indexOf("[BOZZA AD USO INTERNO:")!=null) {
    ultimo.moveToTrash();
  }
  // Set the text in the draft adding a counter to check the order :-D
  t.createDraftReply("[BOZZA AD USO INTERNO: "+j+"]");
  // Add to the label
  t.addLabel(etichetta);
  //break;
}

}
```